# Ceedling CMock settings for ARM STM32

Tags: c, mocking, arm, stm32, cmock

I've been setting up Ceedling for STM32. The howto is very scarce, so far I've managed to google next to nothing. Fortunately, the framework is relatively transparent for its size. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37078332/ceedling-how-to-pass-defines-to-cmock) is a PIC configuration. I set up something similar (`project.yml`):

```
...
:defines:
  # in order to add common defines:
  #  1) remove the trailing [] from the :common: section
  #  2) add entries to the :common: section (e.g. :test: has TEST defined)
  :commmon: &common_defines #[]
    - STM32F103xB
    - UNITY_INT_WIDTH=32
    - CMOCK_MEM_INDEX_TYPE=uint32_t
    - UNITY_LINE_TYPE=uint16_t
  :test:
    - *common_defines
    - TEST
  :test_preprocess:
    - *common_defines
    - TEST
```

So far so good (no real work is yet attempted). Having added this definition

```
    - CMOCK_MEM_PTR_AS_INT=uint32_t
```

I'm having a warning:

```
/vendor/ceedling/vendor/cmock/src/cmock.c:105:40: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
   index = *(CMOCK_MEM_INDEX_TYPE*)((CMOCK_MEM_PTR_AS_INT)next - CMOCK_MEM_INDEX_SIZE);
```

No wonder, as `next` is a PC platform 64-bit pointer. Still I am not at all sure whether I have to control `CMOCK_MEM_PTR_AS_INT` or not. It depends on whether `CMOCK_MEM_PTR_AS_INT` is a critical target (ARM) platform definition.

So far I haven't found an STM32 example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the hard won sequence, complete with the Eclipse integration:

Install Ceedling:

```
$ gem install ceedling
```

Create Ceedling project (troubleshooting [#215](https://github.com/ThrowTheSwitch/Ceedling/pull/215)):

```
myproject $ cd ..
$ ceedling new myproject
$ cd myproject/vendor/
$ rm -rf ceedling/
$ git clone --recursive https://github.com/throwtheswitch/ceedling.git
```

Modify `vendor/ceedling/plugins/module_generator/config/module_generator.yml`:

```
:module_generator:
  :project_root: ./
  :source_root:  Src/
  :inc_root:     Inc/
  :test_root:    test/
```

Modify `project.yml`:

```
...
:paths:
  :test:
    - +:test/**
    - -:test/support
  :source:
    - Src/**
  :include:
    - Drivers/**
    - Inc/**
  :support:
    - test/support
...
:defines:
  :commmon: &common_defines  # A nice typo, next to invisible :)
    - STM32F103xB
...
:cmock:
  :strippables:
    - volatile
...
:plugins:
  :load_paths:
    - vendor/ceedling/plugins
  :enabled:
#    - stdout_pretty_tests_report
    - stdout_gtestlike_tests_report
    - module_generator
```

Eclipse C/C++ Unit plugin configuration:

- Main/Project: myproject
- Main/Application: `/home/user/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/bin/ceedling`
- Main/Disable auto build
- Arguments/Program arguments: clobber\ntest:all
- Testing/Test Runner: Google Test Runner
- Environment: Variable TERM Value xterm